# One class learning to make predictions using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, svm, libsvm

I am using MATLAB to build a prediction model which the target is binary.
The problem is that those negative observations in my training data may indeed are positives but are just not detected.

I started with a logistic regression model assuming the data is accurate and the results are less than satisfactory. After some research, I moved to one class learning hoping that I can focus on the only the part of data (the positives) that I am certain with.

I looked up the related materials from MATLAB documentation and found that I can use `fitcsvm` to proceed.

My current problem is:

1. Am I on the right path? Can one class learning solve my problem?
2. I tried to use `fitcsvm` to create a `ClassificationSVM` using all the positive observations that I have.

```
model = fitcsvm(Instance,Label,'KernelScale','auto','Standardize',true)
```

However, when I try to use the model to predict

```
[label,score] = predict(model,Test)
```

All the labels predicted for my Test cases are 1. I think I did something wrong. So should I feed the svm only the positive observations that I have?
If not what should I do?